# How to specify -std=c++11 option in bazel BUILD file?

Tags: c++, c++11, target, bazel

How to add this option into a target description section?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `bazel build --cxxopt='-std=c++11'` to  `.bazelrc` file.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, actually adding --cxxopt='-std=c++11' to  .bazelrc should work.

Answer (score 1):

> export BAZEL_CXXOPTS=-std=c++11

[see source](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/unix_cc_configure.bzl#L364)

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting it globally in `.bazelrc`  or using `BAZEL_CXXOPTS` , you can also set them individually for each target in their `cc_binary` or `cc_test` rules:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "target1",
    srcs = ["target1.cc"],
    copts = ["--std=c++17"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "target2",
    srcs = ["target2.cc"],
    copts = ["--std=c++14"],
)
```