# Error: C++ versions less than C++14 are not supported in Bazel. How to resolve?

Tags: gcc, bazel

I am trying to build my project using Bazel and I keep getting the following error:

```
vbnet

In file included from external/com_google_absl/absl/base/config.h:86,
                 from external/com_google_absl/absl/debugging/stacktrace.h:34,
                 from external/com_google_absl/absl/debugging/stacktrace.cc:37:
external/com_google_absl/absl/base/policy_checks.h:79:2: error: #error "C++ versions less than C++14 are not supported."
   79 | #error "C++ versions less than C++14 are not supported."
      |  ^~~~~
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.602s, Critical Path: 0.66s
INFO: 74 processe
```

My conda environment supports `12.2.0` version of gcc. I checked and found no rc file to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665744/how-to-specify-std-c11-option-in-bazel-build-file). I tried with `BAZEL_CXXOPTS=-std=c++11`. None of them worked.

What else can I do to fix this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not Bazel, but abseil. For some reason you try to use a abseil version that works only with C++14. Downgrade to an abseil version that supports C++11 or whatever ou need

Comment: @Vertexwahn Do you know how to modify this to downgrade abseil?

`http_archive(
    name = "com_google_absl",
    strip_prefix = "abseil-cpp-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/archive/master.zip"],
)`

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions:

**Downgrade Abseil**

Downgrade in your `WORKSPACE` (or `WORKSPACE.bazel`) file to an Abseil version that supports C++11 - assuming that git commit hash `273292d1cfc0a94a65082ee350509af1d113344d` is old enough:

```
   load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

   http_archive(
      name = "com_google_absl",
      urls = ["https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/archive/273292d1cfc0a94a65082ee350509af1d113344d.zip"],
      strip_prefix = "abseil-cpp-273292d1cfc0a94a65082ee350509af1d113344d",
    )
```

Master is always pointing to the newest Abseil version that requires since some time C++14 (see release notes -> "Abseil now requires at least C++14")

**Build with a config**

GCC 12.2.0 is fairly new and supports C++14, but you have to tell GCC that it should use C++14 or up

Create a `.bazelrc` file in the root of your workspace - add this content:

```
# GCC 12
#build:gcc12 --cxxopt=-std=c++23
build:gcc12 --cxxopt=-std=c++20
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-Wall
```

Now build with `bazel build --config=gcc12 //...` or run with this config (e.g. `bazel run --config=gcc12 //some:target`

Comment: I had to set both `--host_cxxopt=-std=c++14` and `--cxxopt=c++14` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In your `cc_library` or `cc_binary` that depends on absl, you can set `copts`.

E.g.,

```
cc_library(
  name = "foo",
  deps = ["@com_google_absl//:foo"],
  copts = ["-std=c++14"],
)
```